# Segmentation fault in recursive function returning list

Tags: c++, list, recursion, segmentation-fault

I have a recursive function, that is returning a list of structs.

```
struct Neighbour_node{
    int index;
    double dist;
};
```

And here is the function:

```
list<Neighbour_node> findNewNeighbours(int original, int particle, int k){
    Neighbour_node node;
    list<Neighbour_node> neighbours;
    list<Neighbour_node> temp_neighbours;
    list<Neighbour_node>::iterator iterator;

    if (k <= 0){
        if (particle == -1){
            node.index = -1;
            node.dist = 1000.0;
        }
        else{
            node.index = particle;
            node.dist = glm::length(hair[original].position - hair[particle].position);
            neighbours.push_back(node);
        }
    }
    else {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < hair[particle].neighbours.size(); i++){
            temp_neighbours = findNewNeighbours(original,hair[particle].neighbours[i],k - 1);

            temp_neighbours.sort(compareNeighbour_node);
            neighbours.merge(temp_neighbours,compareNeighbour_node);
        }
    }
    return neighbours;
}
```

Line:

```
temp_neighbours = findNewNeighbours(original,hair[particle].neighbours[i],k - 1);
```

causes segmentation fault and I am not sure why. I have seen examples with line similar to my erroneous one and it seems, it is not wrong. But those functions were not recursive, so I am guessing that this is where the problem is - besides, when k = 0 (only one call of a function - thus as if it wasn't recursive), then it doesn't crash. Can anyone, please, help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried checking if `particle` has a value outside of the bounds of `hair`?

Comment: You could save us a lot of guesswork with a minimal complete example.

Comment: @GWW Thanks, you were right, I thought I checked it in the beginning, but I didn't realize, that the check will be performed only in the deepest recursion step (k==0). It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Check the stack size in your os.

ulimit -s

I suggest that it is because of stack.
Becase the stack you need seems increase rapidly.

Show your "hair" for more detail for us to see.